# How to check the distinct number of characters in a string

Tags: python

My code is supposed to check the distinct number of characters of a string and say if it's odd or even but for some reason it keeps on saying ODD.

```
string=str(input())
for i in range(0,len(string)):
flag=0
for x in range(0,len(string)):
    if(string[i]==string[x] and i!=x):
        flag=1
        break
if(flag==0):
    check = string[i]

if len(check) % 2 != 0:
print('ODD')
else:
print('EVEN')
```

Comment: You seem to have some indentation problems with the if-else at the end of your script.

Comment: Not just the if-else at the end: the first for loop is also not indented.

Comment: What is `check`? Is it a single char?

Comment: Two tips: 1/ parentheses are usually not needed in if-statement. That means you either learned this from a bad source, or you are used to a language like C. 2/ the `set` type is incredibly useful when it comes to *distinct* items. It is absolutely worth your time reading up on `set` in the documentation.

Comment: There are faster ways of getting the distinct characters of a string in Python other than looping over every character and each following character

Comment: @kuro well it's supposed to be the result of removing unnecessary characters and I thought I could've just used len but it doesn't work

Comment: @user19374990, `check` is then a one character string, so `len()` will always be 1. So your code will always print odd. You might have meant `check += string[i]`

Comment: @kuro okk thx, ill try to keep this in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
text = 'Hello this is a test'

unique_letters = set(text.lower())
unique_letters.remove(' ')

print(unique_letters)

print ('odd') if len(unique_letters) % 2 else print ('even')
```

Result:

```
{'o', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'i', 's', 'a', 't'}
even
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing like that.

**Do like this:**

```
string = str(input())
arr = set(list(string))
total = len(arr)

if total % 2 == 0:
    print('EVEN')
else:
    print('ODD')
```

**Explanation:**

1. To avoid multiple loops and optimize the program, convert string to a list using the **list()** function.
2. To make the list unique, Use the **set()** function
3. Finally **len()** function for the count.

Comment: @9769953 Ok, done!

Comment: @9769953 This was done to make code more explicit.

Comment: @9769953 I felt for a beginner like OP, it is important to explicitly show all steps, they can be more Pythonic later in their career.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question but if you'd like to put the even and odd numbers in separate lists, you can use List Comprehension with `enumerate` to accomplish this.

```
even_letters = [c for i, c in enumerate(word) if i % 2 == 0]
odd_letters = [c for i, c in enumerate(word) if i % 2 == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if len(set(input())) % 2:
    print('ODD')
else:
    print('EVEN')
```

how does it work?

`set`: get all unique letters from `input()`. `input`'s output is `str` and sequence and if you pass it to set, output is all unique letters.
example:
str("asdad") # -> {"a","s","d"}

`len`: return length of input. for example, it returns `3`